# Email Deliverability settings getting set to 'System Email Only'

Tags: email, deliverability

So as my title says I am changing my Email deliverability settings to 'All Email' and testing my applications, but after few days this setting is automatically getting changed to 'System Email Only'. What could be the reason for this? Does salesforce set this to 'System Email Only' based on some condition. Please let me know.

[image: Deliverability]

Comment: Are you refreshing that sabdbox or using any CI Job?

Comment: nope i know during refresh it happens but i am not doing any refresh. and by CI you mean continuous integration?

Comment: There is an integration which is happening from Salesforce - NetSuite in which I am using OAuth 1.0 for authentication, also I am using consumerKey & consumerSecret to prepare header & signature. Does this impact the deliverability settings?